# React to a modified directory

Tags: files, directory, find

In linux everything is considered as file, Now if I want to find only folders/directories not the files then how can i do that?

I am getting all the modified files with the following command.

```
find /Users/ghanshyam -type f -mmin -5 -print
```

My goal is to generate the log file with all the modified/access folders. Here two options are available.

- create a module and call every time when a folder is modified (this one is bit difficult
  because I need to check particular event)
- create a cron task that will run after every 5 minutes. cron task will execute shell
  script and generate the log entries with the modified folders.

Do you have any other option to do this task ?

Comment: you can print directories using -type d in place of -type f

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find . -type d` to list the directories. `find` command with **iname** option will filter out the results that is needed for you.

To get the modified files, **-mmin** should work perfectly. Also give a try with **-mtime** option. Apart from this to get the modified files under a directory, you can use `dnotify` program. Check this [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/dnotify.1.html) for usage.

Redirect the output a log file `find /Users/ghanshyam -type f -mmin -5 -print > modified_log`

About the options available for running your command:

- Write a script to run the command every 5 mins with sleep interval
- create a cron job
- use `watch` command and put it in background
- create a daemon

Comment: dnotify has been obsoleted by inotify.(dnotify is not present in my system)

Comment: @Deepak Check out the man page link I gave in the answer. As mentioned by you there are other programs like inotify exists to do the job.

Comment: Dnotify is not not present in my ubuntu neither. Your man page link doesn't show any alternatives to this program. Are there any?